# How to get these gender choices to display as radio buttons

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

I am relatively new to Django and I have no idea how to get the gender choices in my Models to my views and then to my templates.
Below is my Models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from model_utils import Choices

class Country(models.Model):
    ''' define a table in the database called Country with several variables.'''

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique = True)
    officiallang = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    size = models.IntegerField()
    # TODO: Find out how to defined this relationship
    # representative = models.OneToOneField(UNrepresentative)

class UNrepresentative(models.Model):
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
            ('M', 'Male'),
            ('F', 'Female'),
            ('O', 'Other'),
        )

    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, unique = True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1,choices = GENDER_CHOICES,)
    country = models.OneToOneField(Country, on_delete = models.CASCADE, )


class CountryForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Country
        fields = ['name', 'officiallang', 'size']

class UNrepresentativeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UNrepresentative
        fields = ['name', 'gender', 'country']
```

Below is my Forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from app1.models import Country, UNrepresentative

class CountryForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 50,)
    officiallang = forms.CharField(max_length = 50)
    size = forms.IntegerField()

class UNrepresentativeForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(max_length = 100,)
    gender = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices = UNrepresentative.GENDER_CHOICES,)
```

Finally, here is create_representative.html which contains the templates code:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<form method = 'POST' action = "{% url 'create_representative' %}">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="name" value = "" name = 'name'>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
                <div>
                        <label>Male</label>
                        <input type="radio"  placeholder="gender" value="male" name='gender'>
                </div>
                <div>
                        <label>Female</label>
                        <input type="radio"  placeholder="gender" value="female" name='gender'>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class = 'col-4'>
                <label for="country">Choose a country:</label>
                <select name="country_id">
                        {% for items in all_items %}
                                <option value="{{items.id}}">{{items.name}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                </select>
        </div>
        <div class = 'col'>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Create rep</button>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
{% endblock content %}
```

I have manually added male and female in values but ideally what I want to have is a dropdown with radio buttons to choose one of the genders. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.